# Issue while installing LayerKit in my project

Tags: ios, swift, chat, cocoapods

I am installing layer in my project.This is my POD Spec.
This is the project i am using.
https://github.com/layerhq/Layer-Parse-iOS-Example
It is running fine. But when i tried to import Atlas and layer in my project it is not working.
My pod version is 0.39.0

```
platform :ios, '8.0'

use_frameworks!


pod 'Atlas', '< 1.0.14'
pod 'LayerKit', '>= 0.17.0'
pod 'Parse','~>1.8.5'
pod 'ParseUI'
pod 'ParseFacebookUtilsV4','~>1.8.5'
pod 'ParseTwitterUtils','~>1.8.5'
pod 'ParseTwitterUtils','~>1.8.5'
pod 'DKImagePickerController'
pod 'FormatterKit', '~> 1.8.0'
pod 'UIImageEffects', '~> 0.0.1'
pod 'Synchronized', '~> 2.0.0'
pod 'TTRangeSlider'
```

Error Log in my application.

Undefined symbols

```
 for architecture x86_64:
  "_LYRClientObjectChangesUserInfoKey", referenced from:
      -[ATLConversationViewController layerClientObjectsDidChange:] in ATLConversationViewController.o
  "_LYRClientObjectsDidChangeNotification", referenced from:
      -[ATLConversationViewController atl_registerForNotifications] in ATLConversationViewController.o
  "_LYRConversationDidReceiveTypingIndicatorNotification", referenced from:
      -[ATLConversationViewController atl_registerForNotifications] in ATLConversationViewController.o
  "_LYRConversationOptionsDeliveryReceiptsEnabledKey", referenced from:
      -[ATLConversationViewController conversationWithParticipants:] in ATLConversationViewController.o
  "_LYRMessageOptionsPushNotificationConfigurationKey", referenced from:
      _ATLMessageForParts in ATLMessagingUtilities.o
  "_LYRTypingIndicatorParticipantUserInfoKey", referenced from:
      -[ATLConversationViewController didReceiveTypingIndicator:] in ATLConversationViewController.o
  "_LYRTypingIndicatorValueUserInfoKey", referenced from:
      -[ATLConversationViewController didReceiveTypingIndicator:] in ATLConversationViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_LYRCompoundPredicate", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ATLConversationViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_LYRConversation", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ATLConversationListViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in ATLConversationViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_LYRMessage", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ATLConversationViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_LYRMessagePart", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ATLMessagingUtilities.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_LYRPredicate", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ATLConversationListViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in ATLConversationViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_LYRPushNotificationConfiguration", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ATLMessagingUtilities.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_LYRQuery", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ATLConversationListViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in ATLConversationViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

Comment: Please post the cocoapods version, and the `pod install` output

Comment: It's not showing any errors.And is posted my pod version.

Answer (score 0):

You are using two pod 'Atlas' and 'LayerKit'
pod 'Atlas', '< 1.0.14'
pod 'LayerKit', '>= 0.17.0'

you need to add only pod 'Atlas', '< 1.0.14' because it's automatically to install the LayerKit Framework.

after the pod installing.Please add the atlas framework in buildPhases. I have also attached the images.[image]

Please right on your podfile. You also need to set the you project name in target
[image]

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.